# Poltergeist JS/Headless Chrome - Switch to offline mode

Tags: cucumber, google-chrome-headless, poltergeist

I am looking to write a test where I can switch between Offline mode and back to Online mode mid way through a Cucumber test. I can manually achieve this via Dev Tools in Chrome but is there a way to automate this using Poltergeist JS or Headless Chrome?

I know that `page.driver` is accessible, in fact I use this for setting cookie values in another test

```
Given(/^I set the "([^"]*)" cookie value to "([^"]*)" for the domain "([^"]*)"$/) do |cookieName,cookieValue,cookieDomain|
  if "#{DRIVER}" == "headless_chrome"
    page.driver.browser.manage.add_cookie name: cookieName, value: cookieValue, domain: cookieDomain
  else
    page.driver.set_cookie(cookieName, cookieValue, {:domain => cookieDomain})
  end
  sleep 1
end
```

Unless I'm missing something I can't see how to switch between Offline and Online modes. How can I do this in my test setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Selenium with Chrome as the driver you can use [network_conditions=](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_extensions/has_network_conditions.rb#L44)

```
page.driver.browser.network_conditions = { offline: true }
```

I don't believe Poltergeist had similar functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the provided answer, helped a lot, i did have to specify `page.driver.browser.network_conditions = { offline: true, latency: 0, throughput: 0 }` in my case, putting it here incase it helps someone else